# Rotating an image in AngularJS without CSS and saving it

Tags: html, angularjs, image, css

I'd like to be able to rotate clockwise an image in AngularJS2,4,5 in environment but all of my findings are doing it with CSS. But the rotated image is supposed to be saved, and next time appears as default.

Any library suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with `<canvas>`, which uses **WebGL**. Here is a simple example of rotating an image by 90 degrees with just button clicks.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var angleInDegrees = 0;

  var image = document.createElement("img");
  image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(image, canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - image.width / 2);
  }
  image.src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded";
  $scope.clockwise = function() {
    angleInDegrees += 90;
    drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
  }
  $scope.counterclockwise = function() {
    angleInDegrees -= 90;
    drawRotated(angleInDegrees);
  }

  function drawRotated(degrees) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(degrees * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.width / 2);
    ctx.restore();
  }

});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas><br>
  <button ng-click="clockwise()">Rotate right</button>
  <button ng-click="counterclockwise()">Rotate left</button>
</div>
```

To download it, I think you need to have `canvas.toDataURL('image/png');`, which will return a link that you can use to download your image

Comment: can you refactor your solution to Angularjs 2 or 4 please?

Comment: @AliSaberi they are completely different, so no, I can't. Next time tag your question with `angular` and not `angularjs`. Keep in mind that WebGL is independent from angular framework, so maybe you can adopt my code to your example